# Vue select and other Vue library import to new Vue with npm without using CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm just start use Vue in my flask application (use Vue components only in a some template not in all project) and i'm stuck when i need to use some Vue extentions (for example Vue-dropzone) and found there is no CDN for this Vue-library. So i try to start use npm to undestand how to import some models without using CDN and i'm stuck because there is simple example which i want to implement but it doesn't work. Could anybody help me figured out how to import Vue extension using npm install without using CDN.

Below is simple index.html where i try to use Vue-select without using CDN (with CDN this is work well).

```
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>

     <div id="app">
      <h1>Vue Select</h1>
         <v-select  :options="options" :reduce="item => item.supp_name" label="supp_name" v- 
       model="selected">

     </v-select>

     <pre>{{$data.selected}}</pre>
    </div>


  <script>


    import Vue from 'vue'
    import vSelect from 'vue-select'

    Vue.component('v-select', VueSelect.VueSelect)
     new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data: {
    options: [

        {"id":20,"supp_name":"test1"},
        {"id":21,"supp_name":"test2"},
        {"id":34,"supp_name":"supertest"}
        ],

        selected:"",
        }

        })
      </script>
```

Comment: Are you actually using a bundler to bundle/pack the dependencies?

Comment: Do you have a node project? Did you use `npm install`? I fear this question has too many unknowns to even come close to being able to help you

Comment: Yes I use npm install it install npm modules and I try to import models but it cause an error

Comment: @Terry I have no idea unfortunately what is a bundler

Comment: @T.Short could you please let me know what exactly  I need provide to have a chance solve this issue?

Comment: CDN for vue-dropzone: https://unpkg.com/vue2-dropzone@3.5.9/dist/vue2Dropzone.js
CDN for vue-select: https://unpkg.com/vue-select@2.5.1/dist/vue-select.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download vue.js from https://unpkg.com/vue@latest
2. In the page, replace the value of src in .
   changes

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="./vue.js"></script>
```